# Drop down list appears after the page loads, how to access this new DOM element?

Tags: jquery

I need to attach a 'change' event to a dropdownlist.

This dropdown list is dynamically added to the page AFTER it has loaded.

So this curretnl doesn't work:

$("#mydropdown")

Since it wasn't in the DOM when the page finished loading.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work? it works if it executes after the drop down has been added to the DOM. How are you trying to access it? is it inside an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach events to all current and future objects that match the selector.

```
$('#mydropdown').live('change', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element isn't there when the page loads, then just select it when it ***is*** there.